# Table is mispositioned in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have bunch of inline div's, followed by a block div. Inside block div, there should be table, something like that:

```
<div class="myInlineDiv"></div>
<div class="myInlineDiv"></div>
<div class="myBlockDiv">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Problem is: table is misaligned in FireFox. It works well in Chrome and IE.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zk9eD/2/ Red block should be in yellow area.

(I can fix position problem with position: inline; but it causes another problem with table width).

Comment: There is no `position:inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left;` in table class

```
.table1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Check working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zk9eD/5/